# Pushing dom element into window.open() destroys the originating page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykje3n1z/)

When running the following code, I expect it to open the content in a new window.

It works as expected, but produces an issue where it destroys the pushed content from the originating page.

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    const html = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.lastChild;
    const win = window.open(
      '',
      '_blank',
      'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top=' + (screen.height - 400) + ',left=' + (screen.width - 840));
    win.document.body.style.margin = '0px';
    win.document.body.appendChild(html);
  }
</script>

<div onclick="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>This is just a sample to show what is happening</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see an example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykje3n1z/) as I could not get the script to work on here.

Why does the code remove the content from the page?

Is there a better way to approach this in vanilla JS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.lastChild;` yikes `closest()` is a better solution.

Comment: clone the element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the element before you append it

```
win.document.body.appendChild(html.cloneNode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
win.document.body.innerHTML = html.innerHTML
```